# Magento 2 add multiple variations configurable product to cart at one time

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, addtocart

I am trying to add multiple variations configurable product to cart at one time but it shows following error

> jquery.js:9666 POST http://127.0.0.1/magento216/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tYWdlbnRvMjE2LzI1MDMtbWVucy1zaGlydHMuaHRtbA,,/product/62/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

My code is:

```
  public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
    }
    //$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $eparams =    array ('uenc' => 'aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tYWdlbnRvMjE2LzI1MDMtbWVucy1zaGlydHMuaHRtbA,,',
        'product' => '62',
        'selected_configurable_option' => '',
        'related_product' => '',
        'form_key' => 'ZTLmXAr9YrxjJM9U',
        'super_attribute' =>
            array (
                93 => '5',
                199 =>
                    array (
                        1 => '11',
                        2 => '10',
                        3 => '9',
                        4 => '8',
                    ),
            ),
        'qty' => '1',
    );

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/step1.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($eparams['super_attribute']['199']);

    foreach($eparams['super_attribute']['199'] as $item){

        $params =  array ('uenc' => 'aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tYWdlbnRvMjE2LzI1MDMtbWVucy1zaGlydHMuaHRtbA,,',
            'product' => '62',
            'selected_configurable_option' => '',
            'related_product' => '',
            'form_key' => 'ZTLmXAr9YrxjJM9U',
            'super_attribute' =>
                array (
                    93 => '5',
                    199 => $item
                ),
            'qty' => '1',
        );

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/step2.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($params);

        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface')->getLocale()]
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

        /**
         * Check product availability */

        if (!$product) {
            return $this->goBack();
        }

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($params);

        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);

    }

    if (!empty($related)) {
        $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
    }
    //$this->newProduct();

    $this->cart->save();
    //exit;

    /**
     * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
     */
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
        ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
    );

    if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
        if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
            $message = __(
                'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                $product->getName()
            );
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
        }
        $this->newProduct();
        return $this->goBack(null, $product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define each time new product object to add multiple product at one time,

In above your code, each time product generate from  `$product = $this->_initProduct();` line.

**So you have to create new product object instead of those line, you can just comment out those line and keep below code,**

```
 $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();                
   //$product = $this->initProduct();
 $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($params['product']);
```

**Using above way each time new Product Object creates and add multiple product for configurable.**